# Java Comparator not working with Generic type when reversed

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have an arraylist that I want to sort based on the amount of `items` that it contains.

My POJO looks

```java
public class Order {

    private final UUID orderId;

    private String buyerEmail;

    private float price;

    private List<Product> items;

    private Date createdAt;
```

I have now made to comparator functions like such to sort in both Ascending order and Descending order.

```java
   case AMOUNT: {
                if(isAscending) this.inMemoryDB.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(order -> order.getItems().size()));
                else this.inMemoryDB.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(order -> order.getItems().size()).reversed());
                return this.inMemoryDB;
            }
```

When I use the statement in the `else` clause to reverse it, it does not know, the type of the object, it only uses a default `Object` type

Giving the following error syntax error

`Cannot resolve method 'getItems' in 'Object'`

Here is my InMemoryDatastore implementation

```java
public abstract class InMemoryDatastore<T> {
    public List<T> inMemoryDB;

    public InMemoryDatastore() {
        this.inMemoryDB = new ArrayList<>();
    }

}
```

Comment: How is `inMemoryDb` typed?

Comment: @GaëlJ I will update question